# How to access elements of a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JSfiddle for an example
http://jsfiddle.net/pAQTn/8/

What i want is my div to be adjacent to the images and i want the text to appear on click of the image 
Another thing i would like is for the text to contain which image no i clicked from 1-4
THIS IS MY HTML

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>
      <img onclick="imgclick()" src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/095/Purple/v4/f3/ac/2f/f3ac2f01-fa54-2dd6-09fc-5cee611d42db/mzl.cakizdof.100x100-75.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="100" height="100" />
  </td>

  <td>
<img onclick="imgclick()" src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/095/Purple/v4/f3/ac/2f/f3ac2f01-fa54-2dd6-09fc-5cee611d42db/mzl.cakizdof.100x100-75.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="100" height="100">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
 <img onlick="imgclick()" src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/095/Purple/v4/f3/ac/2f/f3ac2f01-fa54-2dd6-09fc-5cee611d42db/mzl.cakizdof.100x100-75.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="100" height="100">
  </td>
  <td>
 <img onclick="imgclick()" src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/095/Purple/v4/f3/ac/2f/f3ac2f01-fa54-2dd6-09fc-5cee611d42db/mzl.cakizdof.100x100-75.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="100" height="100">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="txtarea">
    </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
img:hover{
     border:1px solid #0000ff;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;        
}
```

This is my JavaScript

```
function imgclick() {        
    txtarea.innerhtml="You clicked the baby no :";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AjFUb/)

Try this:

```
function imgclick(e) {
    src = (e.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex * 2) + e.parentNode.cellIndex + 1;
    txtarea = document.getElementById('txtarea');
    txtarea.innerHTML = "You clicked the baby no :" + src;
}
```

I am not sure what you want to display on the text no. On my example I put `onclick = "imgclick(this)"` wich will connect the function with the image you click in.
In the example you get the img nr from the table position.

Note also: on your html the 3rd picture has `onlick`, it should be `onclick`

Comment: It might be the index "number" of the image.

Comment: onlick - that's a beautiful name fo event :D

Answer (score 0):

just put number inside: `onclick="imgclick(1)"`, `onclick="imgclick(2)"`, etc. And add parameter to your function

```
function imgclick(num) {
    alert("hey");
    txtarea.innerHTML="You clicked the baby no "+num;
}
```